# Continue code execution after starting infinte loop thread within a class in python

Tags: python, multithreading

In the code below I try to automatically update two databases(rd and dtset) every a specific amount of time. The problem is that as soon as the first thread starts the rest of the code isn't getting executed.

```
class Engine():

    def __init__(self):
        cfg = SafeConfigParser()
        cfg.read('config.ini')
        self.rd_update_interval = float(cfg.get('settings','RD_UPDATE_INTERVAL'))
        self.dtset_update_interval = float(cfg.get('settings','DTSET_UPDATE_INTERVAL'))

    def start(self):
        rd_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_rd_thread(), args=())
        rd_thread.daemon = True                          
        dtset_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_dtset_thread(), args=())
        dtset_thread.daemon = True   
        rd_thread.start()
        print "RD automatic update running..."
        dtset_thread.start()
        print "Dtset automatic update running..."

    def run_rd_thread(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                self.update_rd()
            except:
                pass
            time.sleep(self.rd_update_interval)
        return 0

    def run_dtset_thread(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                self.update_dtset()
            except:
                pass
            time.sleep(self.dtset_update_interval)
        return 0

my_engine = Engine()
my_engine.start()
```

I looked at similar questions and the recommended solution is is to build seperate Thread classes and call them both in my main, but isn't there a way to  do what I want within a single class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `rd_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_rd_thread(), args=())` is the problem.

The issue is that `target=self.run_rd_thread()`, is actually running the `run_rd_thread` method, and trying to use the result of it for the parameter. You want to pass the method itself as the parameter, not the result of the method.

`rd_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_rd_thread)`

should fix this (you don't need to explictly pass `args=()` either, it's the default).

You'll also need to fix the `dtset_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_dtset_thread(), args=())` line in the same way.

Your main script should probably then go into an infinite loop after it calls `my_engine.start()`

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you wanted to be more sophisticated, you could check for the threads finishing/exiting, and then allow the main process to exit with an error message in that case too.

Finally, a couple of minor style points - it's more usual in python to use `while True` rather than `while 1` (even though they're equivalent), and not to bother with the explicit `return 0` when the end of the method is unreachable.